# return function delete some data and print function add None in the output

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I use the print function it returns None.
when I replace it with return some of the data is deleted

```
def email_list(domains):
    for domain in domains:
        for user in domains[domain]:
            return("{}@{}".format(user,domain))
           
        


print(email_list({"gmail.com": ["clark.kent", "diana.prince", "peter.parker"], "yahoo.com": ["barbara.gordon", "jean.grey"], "hotmail.com": ["bruce.wayne"]}))`
```

Comment: The first time your function hits a return statement, it exits the function. That's what `return` means. If you want to return a list, you have to actually assemble a list in your function and return it.

Comment: Also note that there is also an implicit  ‘return None’ at the end of the function which your function can also execute.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for this -

```
def email_list(domains):
    lst = []
    for domain in domains:
        for user in domains[domain]:
            lst.append("{}@{}".format(user,domain))
    return lst
           
print(email_list({"gmail.com": ["clark.kent", "diana.prince", "peter.parker"], "yahoo.com": ["barbara.gordon", "jean.grey"], "hotmail.com": ["bruce.wayne"]}))
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
['clark.kent@gmail.com', 'diana.prince@gmail.com', 'peter.parker@gmail.com', 'barbara.gordon@yahoo.com', 'jean.grey@yahoo.com', 'bruce.wayne@hotmail.com']
```

In your code, the function would end on the first iteration itself. However, you are looking for first creating a list and at last after you are done with your looping, only then return the list.